# Can ClamTK deal with virus in a Windows installation?

Tags: dual-boot, antivirus, clamtk

From my Ubuntu account, I have accessed folders in the partition where Windows is installed. Then I scanned those folders with the antivirus software ClamTK. The output is shown in the following image:

[image: ClamTK output]

Is that a Windows virus? What should I do?

Comment: You should purchase a Windows virus scanner and confirm.  It should give you better options as to whether to disinfect it (if possible) or delete it.  I'm not sure if ClamTK is a valid replacement for a Windows virus scanner...I don't think it is since a virus scanner depends on updated virus definitions and I don't think its definitions for Windows' viruses are up to date.

Comment: Google the output to make sure it is not a false positive.  ClamTK probably not in the top anti-virus, but it's main job on Linux is to scan Windows files.

Comment: Upload the file in question to [VirusTotal.com](https://www.virustotal.com) to see if it matches on some 50+ virus scanners.